# Como llamar desde otra clase a un método dentro de un holderview de un adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando llamar al siguiente método (ActualizarVida) del holder de un adaptador desde otra clase:

```
public static class HolderView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ProgressBar vida;
    ImageView imagenPerso;
    TextView nombrePerso;
    TextView vidaPerso;

    public HolderView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.barraVida);
        imagenPerso = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenPerso);
        nombrePerso = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombrePerso);
        vidaPerso = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vidaPerso);

    }

    public void actualizarvida(int vidanueva){
        vida.setProgress(vidanueva);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void RellenarDatos(Personaje P){
        imagenPerso.setImageResource(P.getImagen());
        nombrePerso.setText(P.getNombre());
        vida.setIndeterminate(false);
        vida.setMax(P.getVida());
        vida.setMin(0);
        vida.setProgress(P.getVida());
        vidaPerso.setText(P.getVida() + " / " + vida.getMax());
    }
}
```

Lo intento llamar aquí:

```
  public void playerMakeMove() {
    do {
        AccionAtaqueBasico accionActual;
        int ataque;
        int defensa;
        int dañofinal;
        int vidadespues;
        String nombredefensor;
        Personaje temporalAtaque;
        Personaje temporalDefensa;
        Personaje defensor;
        if (acciones.isEmpty()){}
        else {
            accionActual = acciones.get(acciones.size() - 1);
            ataque = accionActual.getAtaque();
            defensa = accionActual.getDefensa();
            dañofinal = ataque - defensa;
            temporalAtaque = accionActual.getPersonajeAtacante();
            temporalDefensa = accionActual.getPersonajeDefensor();
            nombredefensor = temporalDefensa.getNombre();
            vidadespues = temporalDefensa.getVida() - dañofinal;
            for (int i = 0; i < enemigosArray.size(); i++) {
                Personaje temporal = (Personaje) enemigosArray.get(i);
                if (temporal.getNombre().equals(nombredefensor)){
                    defensor = temporal;
                    vidadespues = defensor.getVida() - dañofinal;
                    //defensor.setVida(vidadespues);
                    adapterVillanos.actualizarvidatotal(vidadespues);
                }
            }


        }

    }while(comprobarAccion() == true);
```

El adaptador lo tengo declarado mas arriba en el código.
Intento llamar al método pero no me sale el método en las posibles llamadas, he investigado un poco y he visto que la gente recomienda interfaces pero no se muy bien como implementarla, la verdad es que no se hacia que sitio tirar por lo que pido un poco de orientación para saber que poder implementar en mi codigo.

Comment: Hay trucos para hacer lo que pides. PERO! una clase X no deberia acceder a una instancia especifica de un holder, porque esta podria no existir. En todo caso deberias hacer que la clase modifique el valor del array que usa el adapter para crear los holders. Finalmente pedirle al adapter que actualice los datos y listo

Comment: Buenas, probaré lo que comentas, pero la cosa es que cada vez que se modifica el valor tengo que crear adapter y pasarselo o crear el holder?

Comment: no hace falta andar creando el adapter nuevo cada vez que quieras actualizar algo. Solo guarda el adapter en alguna variable y luego le modificas la lista y le pides que se actualice adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();